# How to permanently change a substring of an array? C programming

Tags: c, string, replace, printing

Let's say I have an array which contains an expression of:

```
X1+B*3
```

I then give the user options such that it runs in a while loop:

```
int main(){
   char infix[50];
   strncpy(infix, argv[1], 50);
   infix[50] = '\0';

   int userInput;


   while (userInput != 7){

            printf("Please input a number.\n");
            scanf("%d", &userInput);

                    if (userInput == 1){
                            display(infix);
                    }
                    else if (userInput == 2){
                            numReplace(infix);
                    }
            }
}
```

Option 1 display the current expression and option 2 changes a value of the expression such that numReplace contains:

```
char numReplace(char infix[50])
{
    char rep[50];
    char newstr[50];

    printf("Please enter the variable to be replaced\n");
    scanf("%s", rep);

    printf("Please enter the value to be placed\n");
    scanf("%s", newstr);

    char result[1000] = "";
    char *tmp;
    int len;
    char *k = infix;
    char *res = result;
    while (1)
    {
            tmp = strstr(k,rep);
            if (tmp == NULL)
                    break;
            len=tmp-k;
            tmp=tmp+strlen(rep);
            strncpy(res,k,len);
            strcat(res,newstr);
            res += len + strlen(newstr);
            k = k+len+strlen(rep);
    }
    if (!tmp)
    strcat(result,k);
    puts(result);

}
```

After doing a printing test, the function numReplace does work such that if I choose the variable X1 to be replaced with 2 then the new expression is

```
2+B*3
```

However when I make the user to choose options again, and the user chooses option 1, which is the display option, the expression is reverted back to its normal state of:

```
X1+B*3
```

Can someone please help me out so that the expression is permanently edited by the user input? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always calling `numReplace(infix);` on the *while*. But you never get to change *infix*. On your function `numReplace` you have to alter *infix*, but you create/alter *result*. And it is local to the function. If you alter directly *infix* you solve the problem for more than one iterations.

At the end try using [strcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) , to copy the *result* to *infix*.

```
strcpy(infix, result);
```

You need to make sure that *result* fits *infix*, or else you’ll get a buffer overflow. You can do that allocating both the same size.

Comment: I feel like the solution is really simple but my code still isn't working, i've tried to replace the result variable with infix but of course I don't think that's the solution. Are you able to provide me the code for it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot that strcpy existed